# Magento 2 - Email attachment is not working in my controler

Tags: magento2, email, controllers, attachment

Here is my code.

```
$pdfFile = 'pub/pdf/13_rajeshnagappan2016@gmail.com.pdf';
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('enquiry_test_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
        ->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom('general')
        ->addTo('rajeshnagappan2016@gmail.com', 'Customer Name');
        // ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($pdfFile));

        try {
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(); die;
        }
```

Comment: which error you are facing into this code?

Comment: No errors showing. When I command attachment line email working.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::createAttachment()

Comment: did you referred this link ? https://webkul.com/blog/attach-pdf-file-magento-2-email/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution...

etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Message" type="Offer\Enquiry\Model\Message" /></config>
```

Model/Mail/Message.php

```
<?php 
namespace Offer\Enquiry\Model;

class Message extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Message {

protected $_parts = [];

public function setBodyText($content) {
    $textPart = new \Zend\Mime\Part();
    $textPart->setContent($content)
        ->setType(\Zend\Mime\Mime::TYPE_TEXT)
        ->setCharset('utf-8')
    ;
    $this->_parts[] = $textPart;
    $this->setPartsToBody();
    return $this;
}

public function setBodyHtml($content) {
    $htmlPart = new \Zend\Mime\Part();
    $htmlPart->setContent($content)
        ->setType(\Zend\Mime\Mime::TYPE_HTML)
        ->setCharset('utf-8')
    ;
    $this->_parts[] = $htmlPart;
    $this->setPartsToBody();
    return $this;
}

public function createAttachment($content, $fileType, $disposition, $encoding, $fileName) {
    if($content === null) throw new \Exception("Param 'content' can not be null");
    if($fileType === null) $fileType = 'application/pdf';
    if($disposition === null) $disposition = \Zend\Mime\Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
    if($encoding === null) $encoding = \Zend\Mime\Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    if($fileName === null) throw new \Exception("Param 'filename' can not be null");
    $attachmentPart = new \Zend\Mime\Part();
    $attachmentPart
        ->setContent($content)
        ->setType($fileType)
        ->setDisposition($disposition)
        ->setEncoding($encoding)
        ->setFileName($fileName)
    ;
    $this->_parts[] = $attachmentPart;
    $this->setPartsToBody();
    return $this;
}

public function setPartsToBody() {
    $mimeMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
    $mimeMessage->setParts($this->_parts);
    $this->setBody($mimeMessage);
    return $this;
}
}
```

Model/Mail/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Offer\Enquiry\Model\Mail;
class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
/**
* @param Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment
*/
public function addAttachment($pdfString)
{
    $this->message->createAttachment(
        $pdfString,
        'application/pdf',
        \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        'attatched.pdf'
    );
    return $this;
}
        public function clearHeader($headerName)
{
    if (isset($this->_headers[$headerName])){
        unset($this->_headers[$headerName]);
    }
    return $this;
}
}
```

Controller/Index.php

```
$pdfFile = 'pub/'.$fileName;
   $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
   $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('enquiry_test_template')->setTemplateOptions(
       [
           'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
           'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
       ]
   )->setTemplateVars(
       [
           'message' => 'this is test with send mail',
       ]
   )->setFrom(
       [
           'email' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
           'name' => 'Test'
       ]
   )->addTo(
      'xxxx@gmail.com', 'Receiver'
   )->addAttachment(file_get_contents($pdfFile))->getTransport();
   $transport->sendMessage();
   $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
   $this->sendMail();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are using the right area code

> email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="..." label="This is email template" file="general_template.html" type="html" module="..." area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> template options

```
$templateOptions = [
        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
               ];
```

and in that case your controller class should be in the frontend area too

Comment: {"0":"Warning: Declaration of Offer\\Enquiry\\Model\\Mail\\TransportBuilder\\Interceptor::addAttachment($pdfString) should be compatible with Offer\\Enquiry\\Model\\Mail\\TransportBuilder::addAttachment($pdfString, $pdfFile) in E:\\Rajesh\\xampp7.2\\htdocs\\magento\\generated\\code\\Offer\\Enquiry\\Model\\Mail\\TransportBuilder\\Interceptor.php on line 7",